# setTimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout

I'm animating some process in javascript with this code:

```
  var direction = $('#rightControl');
  function animate()
  {
      if (hover) return;

      if (!direction.is(':visible'))
      {
          if (direction.attr('id') == 'rightControl') direction = $('#leftControl');
          else direction = $('#rightControl');
      }

      doMove(direction);
  }

  // Animate slider!
  setInterval(animate, 2500);
```

Until element `#rightControl` exists at page: call `animate()` function each 2.5 seconds and move my div (inside `doMove`). When the `#rightControl` dissappears I change direction into `#leftControl`, ...

Everything works cool, but when page is in background a few time (for example, 4-5 minutes), the animation becomes crazy and call each 100-200 ms. What's wrong?

Comment: Where is that code invoking `setInterval` located?  Is it in the body of another function, and is it possible that function is being called more than once?

Comment: @kirk-woll it's called in: `$(document).ready(function() { .... } );`. Only once.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/gHZSW/ demonstrates that setInterval is reliable as long as it is above the clamp threshold.

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess is that either `setInterval()` is accidentally being called elsewhere, or `animate()` is.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fXJbW/
It works fine with just `animate()` and `setInterval()`. The problem is in the rest of your code.

Another thing you can do is this:

```
var timeout;

function animate()
{
    // do stuff here
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout=setTimeout(animate,2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, setInterval just adds something to the call-stack every * seconds. If there is some javascript being executed for a few seconds, things might build up on the call stack. That could happen if the page is in background too I guess. Check if it works with setTimeouts (so 1 or a function call to start it, 1 at the end of the function).